# Workable API - Uses deprecated APIs 1 warning found

Tags: javascript, api, deprecated, lighthouse

I have added a Workable API into page and I am facing 1 warning issue that is becoming a hurdle in the page to optimize for best practices.
I checked the Deprecation / Warning section section that only shows "...".
[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Do you have an update? Is it possibly a Chrome bug?

Comment: I don't have it. I think it is a Chrome bug.

Comment: Are you using this policy?

"Header set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000,report-uri="https://example.com/"